# Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, миграция

Работает локально, но не работает, когда делаю deploy на сервер. 
Во время миграции индексов для gem friendly_id

```
-- add_index(:friendly_id_slugs, [:slug, :sluggable_type, :scope], {:name=>"index_friendly_id_slugs_on_slug_and_sluggable_type_and_scope", :unique=>true, :length=>{:slug=>200, :sluggable_type=>50, :scope=>200}})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_friendly_id_slugs_on_slug_and_sluggable_type_and_scope`  ON `friendly_id_slugs` (`slug`(200), `sluggable_type`(50), `scope`(200)) /var/www/projects/design_hse/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:301:in `query'
```

Не могу понять в чём проблема..

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как видно по тексту ошибки, у вас mysql.

[Известное ограничение](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html).

> If you reduce the InnoDB page size to 8KB or 4KB by specifying the innodb_page_size option when creating the MySQL instance, the maximum length of the index key is lowered proportionally, based on the limit of 3072 bytes for a 16KB page size. That is, the maximum index key length is 1536 bytes when the page size is 8KB, and 768 bytes when the page size is 4KB.

В зависимости от настройки innodb_page_size максимальный размер одной записи в индексе ограничен. Для myisam тоже лимит, 1000 байт на запись.

Что делать? Использовать префиксный индекс. Вот только вы пытаетесь сделать уникальный индекс, так что получится или уникальным только префикс или от уникального индекса придётся отказаться вовсе.

Можно пересоздать базу данных и смигрировать данные. Допустимой длины индекса в 3072 байта при размере странички в 16кб вам должно быть достаточно.

И третий вариант - ужимать сами поля данных. 767 байт - это максимум 255 символов utf8 или 191 символ utf8mb4.